# Change the language of a website in Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have been working in my development machine with a Sharepoint installed in English. So the website I created and am woking on appears in English, I have created variations in different languages too (Spanish, Catalan, Basque, Galician). 
Now I realise that the admin part that is in English, should be in Spanish.

I don't know how I could change the language, i have seen the following answer in a [forum](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/mirjam/archive/2008/04/29/changing-the-language-of-an-existing-sharepoint-site.aspx):

> UPDATE dbo.Webs SET Language = 3082

This solves the problem for the language, the admin part of the website appears in Spanish, but when I enter the section of variation labels, it gives me an error.

Can anyone tell me the solution, or which other column in which table must I change (I know it is not recommended)?

Which is the table where it is saved the info about variations?

Answer (score 2):

You should be very careful with modifying the database... not only is it not recommended but it will make your SharePoint environment unsupportable by Microsoft. Good for laughs, not much else.

So to give you the official answer, you cannot do what you are attempting without recreating the website. To quote [Deploy language packs (Office SharePoint Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262108.aspx):

> ...once you choose a language-specific
>   site template for a site or a site
>   collection, the site or site
>   collection will always display content
>   in the language of the original site
>   template.

Comment: Yes, monkeying with the database is just about the worst thing you can do in SharePoint when you don't know exactly what you're doing (which no one does)

Comment: Following what you say, if I have already done the website and I need the admin part to be in Spanish, how can i migrate what i have to another website in a Spanish Sharepoint, and solves this.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't have experience in migrating SharePoint content between different languages. Assuming manually isn't an option, I'm pretty sure you will find something with a web search. There are many tools around.

Comment: Search "content deployment" and "content migration". 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb249963.aspx

Answer (score 1):

An update with no where clause - you may have just set all your variations to use the same language.

You'll also have the issue that keys get created in English, and after you make the change it searches for the keys in Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at our multilingual solution for MOSS
http://www.alphamosaik.com/Pages/Solutions_EN_MultilingualModule.aspx

Regards

Alphamosaik